# transaction count within an interval of time

Tags: sql, sas

I have columns DATETIME, REGISTER_NUM, STORE_ID.
I am attempting to create a variable that counts the number of transactions that occurred within the past 5 minutes of the current transaction.

This is not correct, but I really need help, I am getting discouraged with my lack of experience.

```
SELECT *
WHERE
COUNT(DATETIME >= DATEADD(mi, -5, GETDATE())) AS 5_MIN_INTERVAL_CT
```

Comment: In SQL there is typically a FROM clause that identifies the table from which the data is selected. Is the FROM clause missing in error?  Also post the error message that you receive.

Comment: I'm very confused by this.  Two nearly identical questions ago (both deleted now) I gave you an answer that would work for this.  Why do you keep posting questions?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're looking for something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS 5_MIN_INTERVAL_CT
FROM SomeTable
WHERE DATETIME >= DATEADD(mi, -5, GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 0):

To get number of transactions you ll use

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM YourTransactionTable
WHERE [DATETIME] >= DATEADD(MINUTE, -5, GETDATE())
```

As Rob mentioned it in his comment you do not have a FROM TableName in your query. You have to mention it in your query which table you are selecting your data from.

Answer (score 0):

`DATEADD` and `GETDATE` are not SAS functions; the equivalent functions you are looking for are `INTNX` for the interval and `DATETIME` to get the current system timestamp.  So assuming you have a SAS data set named **mydata** and a variable named **datetime**, this will return the number of records from the previous five minutes:

```
proc sql;
   select count(*) as FIVE_MIN_INTERVALS  /* SAS names begin with letters */
   from mydata
   where datetime >= INTNX('MINUTE',DATETIME(),5)
   ;
```

quit;